# A few questions about properly citing resources according to the APA format

Tags: citations, citation-style, monograph

I recently finished writing a monograph but I am having some slight misunderstandings about how to properly cite the resources I used.

- When mentioning the source of figures, should I write the author's name, title etc. in English or the language that I am writing the text in? I'm writing in Farsi and I write details in Farsi under the figure, should the source be in English? For example, if I'm using the figure 9.2 from page 506 of Zetilli's Quantum mechanics, should I write "[details in Farsi]. N. Zetilli, 2014, p. 506. Wiley" or should I write the equivalent in Farsi?
- Am I allowed to use figures that I found in textbooks or should I ask for explicit consent of the authors?
- I am using numeric citations for citing in-text, like "The magnetic field splits the energy levels [4]" and then mention [4] in the end, is that ok?